# What process determines whether a preprint appears on inspireHEP

Tags: bibliometrics, indexing

I am trying to access the INSPIRE-HEP citation metadata for a lot of preprints, specifically preprints that are (cross)-listed in the quant-ph category on arXiv. A lot of these (roughly 80%) do not appear on INSPIRE-HEP, but I can't tell any obvious pattern as to why.

This difference doesn't seem to be caused by cross-listing in other categories, and I couldn't see any obvious trend in the titles/topics of quant-ph papers that were included on INSPIRE-HEP.

The INSPIRE-HEP FAQ says, "INSPIRE is highly selective to papers within High Energy Physics" but no details are given about how that selection is ultimately made. Is anything more specific known about how preprints are gathered for INSPIRE-HEP?

Answer (score 5):

The [content policy](https://help.inspirehep.net/knowledge-base/content-policy/) details which arXiv categories are indexed:

> ### Types of content included in the HEP Literature Collection
>
> - **arXiv.org e-prints**
>
>   - e-prints from hep*, gr-qc, nucl*, astro-ph.CO, astro-ph.HE, physics.acc-ph, physics.data-an and physics.ins-det archives. Articles cross-listed to these topics are individually evaluated for appropriateness.
>   - Relevant e-prints from other archives (determined from cross-listing, citations or selected on a case-by-case basis).

Preprints in the quant-ph category would be indexed on a case-by-case basis, depending on the topic and at the discretion of INSPIRE. The core topical areas they consider are also laid out in the content policy.